# Set children animate values in SVG "use" element

Tags: svg

I've got an animated spinner SVG file. It's 12 bars in a circle that alter opacity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin: auto; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; display: block; shape-rendering: auto;" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
<g transform="rotate(0 50 50)">
  <rect x="48" y="17.5" rx="0" ry="0" width="4" height="15" fill="#336699">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.9166666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(30 50 50)">
  <rect x="48" y="17.5" rx="0" ry="0" width="4" height="15" fill="#336699">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.8333333333333334s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(60 50 50)">
  <rect x="48" y="17.5" rx="0" ry="0" width="4" height="15" fill="#336699">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.75s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g>
... [and so on, 12 times]
```

This works fine, but it's really repetitive, so I factored out one rect in a defs tag, and used `use` to place it.

```
<defs>
<g id="bar">
  <rect x="48" y="17.5" rx="0" ry="0" width="4" height="15" fill="#336699">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g>
</defs>

<use xlink:href="#bar" transform="rotate(0 50 50)"/>
<use xlink:href="#bar" transform="rotate(30 50 50)"/>
...
```

This also works fine except I need to set the `begin` property in the nested `animate` tag. I've no idea how to reach that. The [MDN for SVG's use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) doesn't seem to talk about altering children of elements made with `use` and searching Google and SO doesn't turn up anything useful, since `use` is such a common word.

I tried `<use xlink:href="#bar" transform="rotate(0 50 50)"><animate begin="-0.9167s"></animate></use>` and a few other things that didn't work.

### How do I set an attribute value of a child of an element made with `use` ?

Thanks all, and as this is my second question on SO, I'm more than open to suggestions on question form/content. Cheers.

To be clear, I don't want to do the animation in CSS or Javascript, I want everything contained in the SVG file. If it's not possible, that's good to know, too.

Comment: instead of animating the rect you can animate the use element

Comment: This is certainly a step in the right direction, the rect code is factored out, but I still end up with the somewhat repetitive:


`<use xlink:href="#bar" transform="rotate(330 50 50)"><animate id="baranimate" attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-0.833s"/></use>`
line repeated 12 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you don't want repetition, you need code to create repetitive lines.
  That can be done with a native Web Component (JSWC)
- If you don't want code, you need to write repetitive lines.

---

**Web Component:**

```js
customElements.define("svg-spinner", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let size = this.getAttribute("size") || 100;
    let background = this.getAttribute("background") || "transparent";
    let fill = this.getAttribute("fill") || "#336699";
    let spokes = new Array(12).fill("").map((_, idx) => {
        return `<rect transform="rotate(${idx*30} 50 50)" fill="${fill}" 
                      x="48" y="17.5" rx="0" ry="0" width="4" height="15">` +
               `<animate attributeName="opacity"  begin="${-(idx/12)}" values="1;0" 
                         keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite">
                </animate></rect>`}).join("")
    let style = `margin:auto;background:${background} none repeat scroll 0% 0%;display:inline-block;shape-rendering:auto`;
    let svg = `<svg style="${style}" width="${size}px" height="${size}px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">` +
               spokes + `</svg>`
    this.innerHTML = svg;
  }
});
```

```html
<svg-spinner size="150"></svg-spinner>
<svg-spinner size="150" fill="green"></svg-spinner>
<svg-spinner size="150" fill="hotpink" background="pink"></svg-spinner>
```

Comment: Just knowing it isn't possible only in the SVG file is valuable to me, thanks. I'll integrate your answer into my JavaScript, cheers.